# useState, react hook with contexAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

i have a very strange problem.
to make a long story short im using react hooks with context api.
when i'm trying to remove item from my state with filter the use state function doesn't start

my data looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo9D8.png)

and my code looks like this, the problem is with deleteUser function: (added only the relevant part):

```
const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
const[users,setUsers] = useState([])

const addUser = (user) =>{
    setUsers([...users,user])
}

const updateUser = (obj) =>{
    deleteUser(obj.UserName)
    addUser(obj)
}

const deleteUser = (us) =>{
 //not working
 setUsers(users.filter(u=>u.UserName!=us))

 //working
let temp  = [...users]
 temp = temp.filter(el=>el.UserName!=us)
 setUsers([...temp]) 
}
```

Comment: both should work while filter function is returning new reference. I think that problem in other code that you have...

Comment: i know, but the first one isn't working.....

Answer (score 1):

try this instead...

```
const deleteUser = (us) =>{
 setUsers(previousUsers => previousUsers.filter(u => u.UserName !== us))
}
```

Comment: @AlexKleymen you have problems somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

What your problem is you are not using !== instead you have written !=

```
const deleteUser = (us) =>{
 //Add an equal sign it will work
 setUsers(users.filter(u=>u.UserName!==us))
```

Comment: Nope, i'm using string so it doesn't matter